# re-attaching files input to an html form

Tags: php, forms

I have a rather extensive form which contains a file input. The form will be returned if there are errors and all the other inputs will be repopulated with the existing $_POST data. It is not possible to re-populate and image input.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how resend the posted file without storing it temporarily on the server (otherwise there could be a large build up of temporary files).

Cheers,

Comment: if you don't store it temporarily for them, then they'll have to upload it again, costing both of you in bandwidth and time and server resources. Seems like it would be easier to save the file temporarily, provide a link on the form showing them they've already uploaded the file, and after a certain amount of time clear out the temporary files that haven't been associated with any completed forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have a way around that...
You have two options here.

1. Do client side form validation (w/ajax if necessary) so that you ensure that the form's content is valid before you submit the form
2. Store the file temporary on the server (deleting files older than 30 mins or so...)

Answer (score 1):

You *could* encode the files using the [data: scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), then stuff that in a hidden input in the form.

… but that would be a horrible waste of bandwidth (especially if the files are on the large side).

Storing temp files and having a sane housekeeping policy (such as delete all files over 10 minutes old every 5 minutes) is the way forward.